# VSCode Jupyter Interactive Window - show long output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

The VSCode Interactive window for Jupyter truncates long output:

```
import os
dir(os)
```

```
['CLD_CONTINUED',
 'CLD_DUMPED',
 'CLD_EXITED',
 'CLD_TRAPPED',
 'DirEntry',
 'EX_CANTCREAT',
 'EX_CONFIG',
 'EX_DATAERR',
 'EX_IOERR',
 'EX_NOHOST',
 'EX_NOINPUT',
 'EX_NOPERM',
 'EX_NOUSER',
 'EX_OK',
 'EX_OSERR',
 'EX_OSFILE',
 'EX_PROTOCOL',
 'EX_SOFTWARE',
 'EX_TEMPFAIL',
 'EX_UNAVAILABLE',
 'EX_USAGE',
 'F_LOCK',
 'F_OK',
 'F_TEST',
 'F_TLOCK',
show more (open the raw output data in a text editor) ...

 'waitid',
 'waitid_result',
 'waitpid',
 'walk',
 'write',
 'writev']
```

This is nice functionality as it stops commands that generate a lot of output from overwhelming the Interactive window.

How can I see the entire output?

I can click on the "show more" link, but the output is in a JSON format which is difficult to read.

```
[
    {
        "metadata": {
            "outputType": "execute_result",
            "executionCount": 8,
            "metadata": {}
        },
        "outputItems": [
            {
                "mimeType": "text/plain",
                "data": "['CLD_CONTINUED',\n 'CLD_DUMPED',\n 'CLD_EXITED',\n 'CLD_TRAPPED',\n 'DirEntry',\n 'EX_CANTCREAT',\n 'EX_CONFIG',\n 'EX_DATAERR',\n 'EX_IOERR',\n 'EX_NOHOST',\n 'EX_NOINPUT',\n 'EX_NOPERM',\n 'EX_NOUSER',\n 'EX_OK',\n 'EX_OSERR',\n 'EX_OSFILE',\n 'EX_PROTOCOL',\n 'EX_SOFTWARE',\n 'EX_TEMPFAIL',\n 'EX_UNAVAILABLE',\n 'EX_USAGE',\n 'F_LOCK',\n 'F_OK',\n 'F_TEST',\n 'F_TLOCK',\n 'F_ULOCK',\n 'GRND_NONBLOCK',\n 'GRND_RANDOM',\n 'MutableMapping',\n 'NGROUPS_MAX',\n 'O_ACCMODE',\n 'O_APPEND',\n 'O_ASYNC',\n 'O_CLOEXEC',\n 'O_CREAT',\n 'O_DIRECT',\n 'O_DIRECTORY',\n 'O_DSYNC',\n 'O_EXCL',\n 'O_LARGEFILE',\n 'O_NDELAY',\n 'O_NOATIME',\n 'O_NOCTTY',\n 'O_NOFOLLOW',\n 'O_NONBLOCK',\n 'O_PATH',\n 'O_RDONLY',\n 'O_RDWR',\n 'O_RSYNC',\n 'O_SYNC',\n 'O_TMPFILE',\n 'O_TRUNC',\n 'O_WRONLY',\n 'POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED',\n 'POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE',\n 'POSIX_FADV_NORMAL',\n 'POSIX_FADV_RANDOM',\n 'POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL',\n 'POSIX_FADV_WILLNEED',\n 'PRIO_PGRP',\n 'PRIO_PROCESS',\n 'PRIO_USER',\n 'P_ALL',\n 'P_NOWAIT',\n 'P_NOWAITO',\n 'P_PGID',\n 'P_PID',\n 'P_WAIT',\n 'PathLike',\n 'RTLD_DEEPBIND',\n 'RTLD_GLOBAL',\n 'RTLD_LAZY',\n 'RTLD_LOCAL',\n 'RTLD_NODELETE',\n 'RTLD_NOLOAD',\n 'RTLD_NOW',\n 'R_OK',\n 'SCHED_BATCH',\n 'SCHED_FIFO',\n 'SCHED_IDLE',\n 'SCHED_OTHER',\n 'SCHED_RESET_ON_FORK',\n 'SCHED_RR',\n 'SEEK_CUR',\n 'SEEK_DATA',\n 'SEEK_END',\n 'SEEK_HOLE',\n 'SEEK_SET',\n 'ST_APPEND',\n 'ST_MANDLOCK',\n 'ST_NOATIME',\n 'ST_NODEV',\n 'ST_NODIRATIME',\n 'ST_NOEXEC',\n 'ST_NOSUID',\n 'ST_RDONLY',\n 'ST_RELATIME',\n 'ST_SYNCHRONOUS',\n 'ST_WRITE',\n 'TMP_MAX',\n 'WCONTINUED',\n 'WCOREDUMP',\n 'WEXITED',\n 'WEXITSTATUS',\n 'WIFCONTINUED',\n 'WIFEXITED',\n 'WIFSIGNALED',\n 'WIFSTOPPED',\n 'WNOHANG',\n 'WNOWAIT',\n 'WSTOPPED',\n 'WSTOPSIG',\n 'WTERMSIG',\n 'WUNTRACED',\n 'W_OK',\n 'XATTR_CREATE',\n 'XATTR_REPLACE',\n 'XATTR_SIZE_MAX',\n 'X_OK',\n '_Environ',\n '__all__',\n '__builtins__',\n '__cached__',\n '__doc__',\n '__file__',\n '__loader__',\n '__name__',\n '__package__',\n '__spec__',\n '_execvpe',\n '_exists',\n '_exit',\n '_fspath',\n '_fwalk',\n '_get_exports_list',\n '_putenv',\n '_spawnvef',\n '_unsetenv',\n '_wrap_close',\n 'abc',\n 'abort',\n 'access',\n 'altsep',\n 'chdir',\n 'chmod',\n 'chown',\n 'chroot',\n 'close',\n 'closerange',\n 'confstr',\n 'confstr_names',\n 'cpu_count',\n 'ctermid',\n 'curdir',\n 'defpath',\n 'device_encoding',\n 'devnull',\n 'dup',\n 'dup2',\n 'environ',\n 'environb',\n 'errno',\n 'error',\n 'execl',\n 'execle',\n 'execlp',\n 'execlpe',\n 'execv',\n 'execve',\n 'execvp',\n 'execvpe',\n 'extsep',\n 'fchdir',\n 'fchmod',\n 'fchown',\n 'fdatasync',\n 'fdopen',\n 'fork',\n 'forkpty',\n 'fpathconf',\n 'fsdecode',\n 'fsencode',\n 'fspath',\n 'fstat',\n 'fstatvfs',\n 'fsync',\n 'ftruncate',\n 'fwalk',\n 'get_blocking',\n 'get_exec_path',\n 'get_inheritable',\n 'get_terminal_size',\n 'getcwd',\n 'getcwdb',\n 'getegid',\n 'getenv',\n 'getenvb',\n 'geteuid',\n 'getgid',\n 'getgrouplist',\n 'getgroups',\n 'getloadavg',\n 'getlogin',\n 'getpgid',\n 'getpgrp',\n 'getpid',\n 'getppid',\n 'getpriority',\n 'getrandom',\n 'getresgid',\n 'getresuid',\n 'getsid',\n 'getuid',\n 'getxattr',\n 'initgroups',\n 'isatty',\n 'kill',\n 'killpg',\n 'lchown',\n 'linesep',\n 'link',\n 'listdir',\n 'listxattr',\n 'lockf',\n 'lseek',\n 'lstat',\n 'major',\n 'makedev',\n 'makedirs',\n 'minor',\n 'mkdir',\n 'mkfifo',\n 'mknod',\n 'name',\n 'nice',\n 'open',\n 'openpty',\n 'pardir',\n 'path',\n 'pathconf',\n 'pathconf_names',\n 'pathsep',\n 'pipe',\n 'pipe2',\n 'popen',\n 'posix_fadvise',\n 'posix_fallocate',\n 'pread',\n 'putenv',\n 'pwrite',\n 'read',\n 'readlink',\n 'readv',\n 'remove',\n 'removedirs',\n 'removexattr',\n 'rename',\n 'renames',\n 'replace',\n 'rmdir',\n 'scandir',\n 'sched_get_priority_max',\n 'sched_get_priority_min',\n 'sched_getaffinity',\n 'sched_getparam',\n 'sched_getscheduler',\n 'sched_param',\n 'sched_rr_get_interval',\n 'sched_setaffinity',\n 'sched_setparam',\n 'sched_setscheduler',\n 'sched_yield',\n 'sendfile',\n 'sep',\n 'set_blocking',\n 'set_inheritable',\n 'setegid',\n 'seteuid',\n 'setgid',\n 'setgroups',\n 'setpgid',\n 'setpgrp',\n 'setpriority',\n 'setregid',\n 'setresgid',\n 'setresuid',\n 'setreuid',\n 'setsid',\n 'setuid',\n 'setxattr',\n 'spawnl',\n 'spawnle',\n 'spawnlp',\n 'spawnlpe',\n 'spawnv',\n 'spawnve',\n 'spawnvp',\n 'spawnvpe',\n 'st',\n 'stat',\n 'stat_float_times',\n 'stat_result',\n 'statvfs',\n 'statvfs_result',\n 'strerror',\n 'supports_bytes_environ',\n 'supports_dir_fd',\n 'supports_effective_ids',\n 'supports_fd',\n 'supports_follow_symlinks',\n 'symlink',\n 'sync',\n 'sys',\n 'sysconf',\n 'sysconf_names',\n 'system',\n 'tcgetpgrp',\n 'tcsetpgrp',\n 'terminal_size',\n 'times',\n 'times_result',\n 'truncate',\n 'ttyname',\n 'umask',\n 'uname',\n 'uname_result',\n 'unlink',\n 'unsetenv',\n 'urandom',\n 'utime',\n 'wait',\n 'wait3',\n 'wait4',\n 'waitid',\n 'waitid_result',\n 'waitpid',\n 'walk',\n 'write',\n 'writev']"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I can take the raw output and massage it in a text editor or other tool.  This is time consuming, so I'm looking for an approach that is built into VSCode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug that has been reported to the VS Code team and has a fix in already. The fix is in VS Code - Insiders (you can install that side by side with stable) to check. The fix should be in stable VS Code in the next full release:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130512

Answer (score 0):

Installing the [JSON formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ClemensPeters.format-json) (or other similar extension) should work to prettify it in VSCode itself.